# Optimize Google Maps loads

Tags: google-maps, optimization, query-optimization

Are there any best practices and advices for optimizing and decreasing number of map loads?

Currently I use AJAX requests, so the page is not loaded many times. But still I'm expecting more than 50K (maybe 100K in the future) map loads per day.

Is only way to pay as you go? And what about the premium plan? How the biggest websites using Google maps solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Don't instantiate the map / panorama until you need it. If you need a panorama and a map, use the internal panorama,

```
panorama = map.getStreetView();
```

as loading it a separate div will incur a second map load.